# Playing with my lower level friend who doesn't have the 'Upgrade Pack Two' DLC

Tags: borderlands-2

I want to play with my friend and I have both the upgrade pack DLCs. I'm level 65 and my friend is level 61. If he doesn't have the Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack Two, will everything still scale to me in his game? We're playing on UVHM.

Comment: Borderlands 2 scales enemies to the level of the host, i.e. If your friend hosts the game (and you join him), you will see enemies scaled to your friend. I'm not sure about upgrade packs because I only have the season pass, and the only other friend that I play with has this also

Comment: the reason i ask is because back when i was 56 and he was 53 even on his host it scaled to me but if he cant even pass 61 it'll just make the game hell for him

Comment: Are you on UVHM? I think that always scales to the highest-level player, regardless of who's hosting.

Comment: yes im on uvhm but its kinda hard to believe they screw over one player for not having dlc another does

Comment: Yep...After seeing the seamless player level-scaling in Guild Wars 2, I get annoyed whenever I go back to Borderlands :/ I guess your only choice is to let your friend host the game in TVHM, so it scales to the host, not the max player level.

Comment: ill just have to setup a new character and speed level to him thank you anyways though

Answer (score 1):

Playthrough One and Two (normal and True Vault Hunter mode) are scaled to the host's level or the host's story progression (based on whether or not the final boss was killed). Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode scales to the highest level player, regardless of whether or not it's possible for the other players in the match to go that high.

If you intend to make a lower level character to play with your friend, I strongly recommend using [Gibbed's save editor](http://blog.gib.me/2013/10/22/borderlands-2-save-editor-revision-224/) rather than manually boosting a new character to save yourself a few hours of pointless grinding.

Comment: as far as editors go i know about them but i have no viable way of bringing them onto my ps3 at the moment so that's not an option and grinding is ok in my book because it should only take a day to catch back up

Comment: @user61508 oh, yeah, not aware of any simple way to edit PS3 saves, only familiar with the PC process